# Access requested fields in resolver mapping template

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

When we request a GraphQL query, for instance,

```
query GetPost {
  singlePost(id: 123) {
    id
    title
  }
}
```

and we have configured a Lambda resolver in AWS AppSync, the request mapping template,

```json
{
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "operation": "Invoke",
    "payload": {
        "resolve": "singlePost",
        "query": $utils.toJson($context.arguments)
    }
}
```

allows us to define the event object passed to the lambda handler.

For the above example, our Lambda handler would be invoked with an event `event` wherein `event.payload.query.id == 123` or the like.

According to  [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html) the `$context` object comprises,

```json
{
    "arguments" : { ... },
    "source" : { ... },
    "result" : { ... },
    "identity" : { ... },
    "request" : { ... }
}
```

**That said, the documentation does not mention where I can access the requested fields of the GraphQL query**.

For the former example, these fields would correspond to `["id", "title"]`.

In the case that I need to resolve some nested properties, e.g. a tags array, of an object through an expensive operation, e.g. a SQL join, it would be beneficial if I could check if this nested property is actually requested.

This question relates to [How to get requested fields inside GraphQL resolver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48004805/how-to-get-requested-fields-inside-graphql-resolver), however, it differs from in the GraphQL implementation `graphql-tools` vs AppSync.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually not something that AppSync supports today, unfortunately. It is, however, a request we've heard from other customers, and I'll use this post as a +1 to prioritize it for a future release.

Comment: Is there any update on this feature? It's something that would GREATLY reduce mapping template bloat in our application.. haven't seen any ongoing conversation about this feature.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html#aws-appsync-resolver-context-reference-info

Answer (score 5):

There is now a `$context.info.selectionSetList` field that includes the requested field names. The [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html#aws-appsync-resolver-context-reference-info) provide an example and explain some special use cases around interfaces and aliases.

Comment: Note that when using `$utils.toJson()` on `context.info`, the values that `selectionSetList` return are not serialized by default. See also https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/4869

Answer (score 0):

The document has been updated, AWS added a new field `info` to the context, you can access the field name as below：

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Invoke",
    "payload": {
      "resolve": "$ctx.info.fieldName",
      "query": $utils.toJson($context.arguments)
    }
}
```

You can refer to the document here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-context-reference.html#aws-appsync-resolver-context-reference-info

Comment: `info.fieldName` is the field on the `parent` that this resolver is being asked to resolve, not the array of field names being requested on the final object that the original question is asking for.