# GraphQL - How to prevent calculating field in resource which not specified in request?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I have a Resource like:

```
{
  a: String
  b: String
  c: [JSON]
}
```

fields a and b are DB object's property, but field c is computed and that computing can take a time.

Problem is whenever I'm making query, it always calculates that field even if query specified only a and b fields to retrieve.

Is there any "graphql ways" to prevent calculating without passing additional parameter which will say to server "don't calculate field c"?

**UPD:**
My resolver is something like:

```
const x = retrieveFromDB(...)
// x = {a: 'x', b: 'y'}
x.c = computingField(...) // it takes a lot of time
return x
```

Comment: Are the items with properties a, b, and c, and JSON graphql Types that you defined? Can you provide more detail regarding property c and how it is computed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL fields are never resolved unless they are explicitly requested.

Let's look at a slightly more complicated example. Let's say we have this schema:

```
type Query {
  getUser: User
}

type User {
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  fullName: String
}
```

And our resolvers look like this:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getUser: () => ({ firstName: 'Susan', lastName: 'Martinez' }),
  },
  User: {
    fullName: (user) => `${user.first_name,} ${user.last_name,}`,
  },
}
```

We return a user object in our `getUser` resolver. We rely on the default resolver behavior for the `firstName` and `lastName` fields, but provide a custom resolver for `fullName`. If we make this query:

```
query {
  getUser {
    firstName
  }
}
```

only two resolvers are called -- the one for `getUser` and the one for `firstName`. However, this query

```
query {
  getUser {
    firstName
    fullName
  }
}
```

will also cause the `fullName` resolver to be called. Each resolver has access to whatever value the parent field resolved to. So if determining the `fullName` is expensive, you can move the logic for evaluating that value into the field's resolver.

On the other hand, if you just need to know which child fields were requested, [there's already an answer for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54988767/6024220).