# Get info object of the request

Tags: typegraphql

I can get query info by using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-parse-resolve-info), as described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40687045/apollostack-graphql-server-how-to-get-the-fields-requested-in-a-query-from-res) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54984035/how-to-know-which-fields-were-requested-in-a-graphql-query). How do I implement same functionality (i.e. get info object of the request) with type-graphql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@Info` decorator to retrieve `GraphQLResolveInfo` value as the parameter.